# Setting updated value to JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, awt, spinner

I have implemented Jspinner in which i have added mouseClicked Listener which sets spinner to current date time but after successful submission of the same the spinner needs to be set to blank which is working fine but when i click on spinner second time then it shows the old value as well as the mouseClicked Listener is not getting called why?
 Note : I am using SpinnerDateModel for spinner.

```
private void spinnerMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
     spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
     ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new DateFormatter(format)));

     ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
         @Override
         public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
             if (0 == ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().getCaretPosition()) {
                 if (((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().getText().length() > 13) {
                     ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setCaretPosition(13);
                 }
             }
         }
     });
}  

private void submit(){
((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setText(null);

}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code :)

Comment: nobody knows, voting to close too

Answer (score 1):

After reading the question several times I think finally get what are you trying to accomplish: every time the user sumbits the info the text must be cleared but when user focuses the spinner again then it must show today's date. Isn't it right?

If so then I'd suggest you don't use `MouseListener` on the `JSpinner` but attach a [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) to the spinner's editor instead. Something like this:

```
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
final JTextField editor = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();

editor.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if(editor.getText().isEmpty()){
            spinner.getModel().setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
});

JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        editor.setText("");
    }
});
```

This way you have these advantages:

- Spinner's model is set just a single time (as it should be).
- When the spinner's editor is focused (both by mouse click or by keyboard navigation) a new date is set to the spinner model *only* if the text was previously cleared.
- Get rid of `MouseListener` which is intended to other purposes.

Comment: I had already tried this thing but focusGained method wont get called from second time onwards.

Comment: How is that? What do you mean *second time onwards*? `focusGained` is called every time the editor gets focused. It should be something else. For instance in your code you're adding a new `CaretListener` to the editor every time the mouse is clicked. So it may not do what is expected though. @JavaLover

Comment: focusGained() is called only first time after that method doesnot get called it's strange. as well as i removed CaretListener from the same but then also focusGained() is not getting called.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Maybe you can share your new code and I'll take a look. Or even better try to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to reproduce this issue. @JavaLover